# Using Action<PointerClass*> as an argument

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, unsafe

I'm creating a performance-critical application that implements image manipulation. I'm using some pixel pointers using my struct named `Pixel` to do some processing. I've got lots of code parts that iterate over the whole bitmap data, and for the sake of code reusability and modularity, I'm designing a method that will take an action and apply it to all pixels of the image (like a map function). However, when I write `Action<Pixel*>` Visual Studio complains about the code saying the type `Pixel*` may not be used as a type argument. The whole class is in an `unsafe` context and I'm using `Pixel` pointers everywhere, but I just can't use a pixel pointer as an Action's template class.

I can use `Action<IntPtr>` but I'll need to convert it to appropriate pointers inside the method body in EVERY iteration, which would kill the whole idea of being "performance critical".

Comment: `The type 'Tools.Imaging.Pixel*' may not be used as a type argument`

Comment: I need a reference to the `Pixel` instance which is a `struct`

Comment: Converting to/from IntPtr isn't going to be a huge performance hit (conversion is largely just informing the compiler that you explicitly want to interpret the data in a particular way).  However, calling through a function pointer for every pixel is going to be a big performance hit.  I would recommend doing some profiling to determine where your bottlenecks really are; pointers in .NET are not necessarily faster [than array accesses, say] (they can actually be slower in some cases) and you might be surprised what things are actually slowing you down.

Comment: I'm usıng Pixel pointers in contrast to using `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` methods of `Bitmap` and it is A LOT faster (without delegates). But I'm using almost the same code OVER and OVER again, where, besides it's boring to copy/paste/change some bits, it is also very prone to typos/logic errors. What is common in ALL of them is that I lock the Bitmap, and "do something" with each pixel by iterating over the pixels using pointers, then unlock the image. I need some ways of passing that operation that I apply to each individual pixel, and it will remarkably make me more productive..

Comment: "*I'm creating a performance-critical application that implements image manipulation.*" - and you chose C# for this... why?  It's not that you can't get good performance out of a managed language, but you'll have to jump through a bunch of hoops and at the end of the day it just isn't worth it.  For what you want to do C or C++ is a better choice.

Comment: well, it's part of a shared library used by both ASP.NET and a C# client software. using pointers the right way, the performance difference between c++ and c# is subtle, and from the productivity side, c# beats c++ hands down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems nothing is forcing you to use `Action<T>`, so you can create your own delegate type. I didn't figure out a way to do this in a generic way, but this works:

```
unsafe delegate void PixelAction(Pixel* ptr);
```

Keep in mind that if this is really performance critical, invoking a delegate is slower than just calling a method directly. Maybe another way could be better, like duplicating code (if that would work in your case), or code generation, either at compile time or at runtime using Reflection.Emit or CodeDOM.

Comment: yes. this answer made me think the same :) working with `Action`s made me forget regular delegates completely, i'll be trying to implement this one.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer types are not classes, and so they can't be used as generic type arguments.

I think your only approach would be to define Action<IntPtr>, and cast as necessary on both sides.  I don't think the performance hit will be as bad as you think when compiling with optimizations.

EDIT: turns out the below doesn't work (CS0208)

<s>Either that, or instead of using Action<T> defining your own delegate type might work:</s>

```
delegate void PointerAction<T>(T* ptr);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: “Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context”. If I add `unsafe`, then: “Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('T')”.